# How to use a EXPO iOS StoreReview API?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, skstorereviewcontroller

I tried to add a EXPO iOS StoreReview API but failed.
have any sample code?

```
import * as StoreReview from 'expo-store-review';
...
export default SettingPage() {
  handleReview = () => {
    if (StoreReview.isSupported()) {
      StoreReview.requestReview();
    }
  };

  render (
    ...
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleReview}>
      <Text>Click Review</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Comment: The code you provided does not work for a variety of reasons, including invalid JavaScript syntax (`export default SettingsPage()` is invalid, `render (` is not a thing) but your call to the StoreReview API is correct. See https://snack.expo.io/@notbrent/store-review?platform=ios to notice that if you write the component properly to call the API it works as expected.

Comment: @brentvatne Thank you for solving.

Answer (score 0):

add ios-appStoreUrl android-playStoreUrl fields in app.json